# How to scroll to a certain item?

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

Is there a way to scroll to a certain item or at least to a selected one?
I'm using TreeListView, but it looks like simple ObjectListView can't scroll by demand as well..

Comment: Winforms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET?

Comment: take a look at here http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/727092-how-scroll-found-item-treeview-listview but it was written in vb.net...

Comment: Winforms, ObjectListView wrapper. I've added tag to the question)

Comment: @tas is that link is useful ?

Comment: @pratap k, actually it isn't. It's about standard controls, but I'm using ObjectListView (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net)

Comment: You may want to just ask on their dedicated forums, as they would hopefully know the answer concerning their own control...  http://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/forums/forum/812922

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
myOlv.EnsureModelVisible(myModelObject)
```

I haven't tested it, but if i remember correctly it is supposed to scroll the view to make the given item/model visible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the item at the top of the list I do something like this and it seems to work:

```
fastObjectListView.EnsureVisible(fastObjectListView.GetItemCount()-1);
fastObjectListView.EnsureVisible(indexToMakeVisible);
```

Answer (score 1):

TreeListView.EnsureVisible(int index) does the job. This function ensures scrolling to the desired item index.

Answer (score 1):

```
objectListView1.TopItemIndex = n;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11230415)

Comment: He wants to scroll OLV and this statement does that.